# Match "*" in OCaml

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

In my OCaml program, I have the following:

```
let rec string_of_list p "" = match p with  
[] -> "[]"
|s::rest -> String.concat " " [Bytes.to_string s; string_of_list rest ""]
```

This piece of code is nested within more code, but when I compile it, I get the error:

```
Warning 8: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
Here is an example of a value that is not matched:
"*"
```

Does the star refer to the Kleene enclosure? I tried fixing the problem by appending the following match:

```
| _ -> "ERROR"
```

but I still the get the same error. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that the parameter you wrote as `""` doesn't match every possible string that the caller could pass to the function. I.e., it's not exhaustive.

For extra help, the compiler picks a string that won't match to illustrate the problem. It is a little strange that it picks the string `"*"`, but that is indeed a string that won't match.

Here's a very simple session showing the same problem exactly:

```
        OCaml version 4.02.1

# let f "" = 44;;
Warning 8: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
Here is an example of a value that is not matched:
"*"
val f : string -> int = <fun>
#
```

Indeed if you pass `"*"` to `f` it will fail (because its parameter is specified by a non-exhaustive pattern):

```
#  f "*";;
Exception: Match_failure ("//toplevel//", 1, 6).
```

That's what the compiler is telling you. There are some parameters that will cause this exception. (In fact all parameters other than the null string will cause the exception).

I don't know why the compiler chooses `"*"` of all possible strings to mention.

(Note that function parameters in OCaml are specified by *patterns*, and `""` is a valid pattern that matches the null string. So the function `f` here is a perfectly valid function that returns 44 when passed the null string and raises an exception for every other string.)

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, the problem was with the function definition:

```
let rec string_of_list p "" = match p with
```

The quotation marks aren't supposed to be there. I'm still curious as to what the * symbolizes though.

Answer (score -1):

you are implicitly matching a string, which is deprecated.

see the following two issues for more info

1. https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/pull/250
2. https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml-manual/pull/13